# Xcode 13 Swift Scroll View Button does not respond

Tags: ios, swift, button, view, scroll

Using Xcode 13, Swift

my goal is to use abscroll view for a bigger User Interface.
I tried several tutorials.

My Problem:
The buttons inside a scroll view do not respond!

Test:
In an absolute minimum example i

1. created a scroll view ,
2. placed a view inside
3. place button inside the view

no code, just GUI builder.

the button inside the scroll view does not operate.

What can be the reason?

Comment: You said you havent added any code, that means you havent dragged an `IBAction` as well from button correct? If thats the case, How do you know buttons not responding? Typically in a straightforward simple set up like that button should work. Also for clarity you mentioned you are trying to use `abscroll view`, you meant `UIScrollView`? I couldnt find such library

Comment: Thank you. After many tries I managed to get the buttons inside the scroll view to respond but I did not find where the error was...